# I'm can't stand with Laravel's Import Excel function

Tags: laravel, import, import-from-excel, laravel-excel

How can I get `Session:get('user_id')` from **UserController.php** or name of meta tag to use into **UserImport.php**?
I have a problem importing data with an Excel file and I need the user id to compare with the table I want to import.

Comment: Are you just looking to get the ID of the logged in user?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Like this

Excel::import(new UserImport(auth()->user()),'users.xlsx');
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/basics.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you using **sanctum**? If so, you can access the `auth()` by using `auth('sanctum')->user()` directly from your controller then just passed it as a return value.

Thanks

Comment: hi @TrJoke, you are welcome :) If ever you solved it already,  just update your question with your answer or either mark the answer that matches with your question :)

Answer (score 1):

$user_id = auth()->id();

This will work with both Web and API.